# Java - synchronized lock hangs tablet (Bluetooth LE Android)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I have a Unity3D app with a Java plugin I've written in Android Studio for accessing a BluetoothLE server over on my Raspberry Pi 3 from my Android device, as well as an Objective-C plugin for XCode on the IOS side for CoreBluetooth. On the plugin side my Objective-C code works perfectly on IOS, but my Java crashes and burns on Android, and freezes the whole tablet, I'm not too surprised. Also notably, it's already taken me about 3x longer so far to code plugin support in Java. Maybe it's time to have a fresh set of eyes looking at it.

The difference is that CoreBluetooth's functions on IOS seem to read a GATT characteristic synchronously while Java requires asynchronous callbacks that don't seem to be working for me. It causes Unity and the entire tablet to hang until reboot.

Here is the part causing problems (it's two parts).

This first part is where I have Unity telling BluetoothLE to go start reading the pins (GetPins). I wanted it to basically act synchronously and wait until it's retrieved data so it can return a string like I've coded in the IOS version so I have it do a synchronized lock.

Basically Java is imposing an asynchronous coding model that's unnecessary on the IOS side (in fact, I'm not so sure there's an asynchronous way to code GATT characteristic reading on IOS CoreBluetooth, but I could be wrong), that would cause me to have to rewrite my entire plugin structure from Unity to support what Java's doing, which is going to be a lot more fiddly in the end and may break other things in the process.

```
    public String GetPins() {
    String returnValue = "";
    if (mConnected) {
        try {
            if (getPinsCharacteristic == null) {
                List<BluetoothGattService> services = mGatt.getServices();
                if (mServiceRead == null) {
                    mGatt.discoverServices();
                    mServiceWrite = mGatt.getService(ServiceWriteUUID);
                    mServiceRead = mGatt.getService(ServiceReadUUID);
                    mServiceNotify = mGatt.getService(ServiceNotifyUUID);
                }
                getPinsCharacteristic = mServiceRead.getCharacteristic(PinsCharacteristic);
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.i("MERRRRRP",String.format("Exception: (%s)",ex.toString()));
        }
        Log.i("MERRRRRP", "Reading Pins");
        if (getPinsCharacteristic != null) {
            try {
                boolean success = mGatt.readCharacteristic(getPinsCharacteristic);
                isReadingPins = true;
                while(isReadingPins) {
                    synchronized (readLockPins) {
                        try {
                            readLockPins.wait(1);
                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                returnValue = new String(getPinsCharacteristic.getValue(), "UTF-8");
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                returnValue = ex.toString();
            }
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Now this is the part onCharacteristicRead where it's actually getting the result back, and should be unlocking the synchronized lock and I should get the value back. Instead the whole tablet is freezing.

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        if (characteristic.equals(getPinsCharacteristic)) {
            synchronized (readLockPins) {
                isReadingPins = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first block of code acquiring lock in a loop and holding it for one second. You assume that your second block of code will execute and acquire the lock between those iterations in first block.

That assumption is wrong. The locks are not fair. If thread A is acquiring and releasing a lock in the loop, and thread B is trying to acquire that same lock, there is not guarantee, that thread B gets it in reasonable time (or maybe never).

The second potential problem (I cannot determine from the code you just posted) is that the variable `isReadingPins` in `while(isReadingPins)` MUST be volatile.

Variables not marked volatile do not trigger memory barrier operation, which results in the scenario where writing to the variable in one thread is not visible in another thread.

In your case, `isReadingPins = false;` in second code block will probably not be visible to the thread running the first code block, because value of the variable will in cache local to the CPU core running that code block, which will always be `true`, because the write to `false` is local to another CPU core and CPU core caches will not be synchronized due to absence of memory barrier. This is why the variable must be volatile.

In the end, this is pretty clumsy way of doing this. I don't know Android API, but in regular Java this would be solved using a promise/future or at least a simple Latch.

*edit* And another thing... if your read function fails, or returns something that is not `GATT_SUCCESS`, then isReadingPins is never set to false and your application just freezes. This is bad design.

Comment: Bear with me I'm fairly new to Java, most of my multithreaded experience is in C#, where it's pretty common to use await/async calls (in Java the closest thing is promise/future). I have to agree with you looking the code over, I could change readLockPins to volatile, and add a conditional to set `isReadingPins = false;` if the condition is not GATT_SUCCESS.

That's fairly easy, but the design is still clunky. So I'm considering either latch (I'm assuming you mean CountDownLatch) or FutureTask.

Comment: Where I need to watch though, is that GetPins could be run multiple times.

Comment: GetPins is a method in my BluetoothPlugin class, and onCharacteristicRead is a method in BluetoothPlugin.mGattCallback, which is a BluetoothGattCallback (Android API). It would have probably been better if I were able to specify my own callback method so I could pass in information about the FutureTask that generated it.